# pass away "from" vs "of"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

When I want to say someone passed away because of a certain reason (cancer, accidents etc), which one would sound more natural between "pass away from" and "pass away of"?

Comment: You can use use _from._ However, _He passed away from an accident_ is far from idiomatic. _Passed away from_ is only appropriate if the cause is a disease: _He passed away from halitosis._ If the cause is an accident, you would have to write _He passed away as the result of an accident,_ or similar.

Comment: Indeed, and even with diseases one often says "passed away as a/the result of". P.S. This is the sort of question where, since both options are not correct, an [Ngram](http://ow.ly/C91630cFTxA) is a very helpful tool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of *cancer* it is not so clear cut

> He died **of** cancer.
>   He died **from** cancer.

are both used.

However in an accident, it is usual to hear

> He died **from** injuries sustained in an accident.
>   He died **in** an accident.

However,

> He died **of** an accident

is incorrect.

Also, you would say

> He died **from** *(too much)* drink. *(correct)*

but not

> He died **from** drinking. *(not correct, but understandable)*
>   He died **of** drink. *(not correct, but understandable)*

Answer (score 1):

One can use "of" or "from" in the phrase you are using, depending on the circumstance involved, but more often one hears people employing a phrase as follows:

> Someone passed away **due** to cancer, an accident or some other reason.

[Definition of due:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/due)

> adjective
>
> 6: required or expected in the prescribed, normal, or logical course of events